# not accept spaces at starting in validations

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

I have form with text field in Magento 1.9. I don't want to accept spaces at starting in text field in validations. Whenever I type space, it is not validating but don't want to accept space at first need to enter any characters in that field.

```
$('#number').keypress(function (e) {
       var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
       var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
       if (regex.test(str)) {
           return true;
       }

       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
});
```

For number i wrote like this but space how to write code.

Comment: Are you asking form admin forms ?

Comment: i want javascript or php

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are asking for admin forms then here is my answer add class `validate-alphanum`

```
    $fieldset->addField('feild_id', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('label'),
        'name'      => 'feild_name', 
        'class'     => 'required-entry validate-alphanum' ,//Add class
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

For js use this condition use `trim()`

```
   if (regex.test(str.trim())) {
       return true;
   }
```

Comment: what is regex? i want only avoid spaces at starting not all

Comment: @Nadh you can use trimLeft()  for this

Comment: it is taking entire field spaces not taking as starting